# Drawing a moving chart using CocoSharp in Xamarin results in slow framerates

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm making a app that will show a line chart of the acceleration meter. The chart has to move sideways to show the new results. To draw i use the CocoSharp graphics library.

First try was to redraw the full chart every update, but this was not fast enough and somehow you cant draw transparent, this wont erase the previously drawn pixels, so my chart just filled up.

Second try was to make the chart 4 times wider than the screen and only draw the last update on 2 positions: at the position we are drawing and 2 screen widths back (out of screen). Before drawing the line i draw a black line instead of transparent to erase the previous result.

I then move the whole layer towards the left, giving a nice scrolling chart. Then when the position exceeds 2 screen widths i reset the position back to 0, but because we are drawing at 2 positions the graph is already drawn the same as where we left, making it seamlessly scroll forever.

This works very good, but after a few minutes of drawing you can notest the screen begins to lagg in framerate. I investigated everything but my drawing thread is working just fine pumping out a full update every 16ms, so i think it is the CocoSharp library.

As i stated before when you draw transparent the pixels do not get erased, which makes me think every draw update keeps in memory somehow, slowing down the gpu after a while. Could this be correct? And if so, how do i fix it?

```
using CocosSharp;
using JumpMeter.Shared;
using JumpMeter.Shared.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace JumpMeter
{
    public class ChartLayer
    {
        public ChartLayer(CCScene scene, float x, float y, float width, float height)
        {
            List = new ConcurrentQueue<CalculationLog>();

            RasterLayer = new CCLayer();
            RasterNode = new CCDrawNode();

            GraphLayer = new CCLayer();
            GraphNode = new CCDrawNode();

            // Add the background layer
            RasterLayer.AddChild(RasterNode);

            // Draw the "zero lines"
            RasterNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(0, height / 2), new CCPoint(width, height / 2), 0.1f, CCColor4B.White);
            RasterNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(0, 2), new CCPoint(width, 2), 0.1f, CCColor4B.White);
            scene.AddLayer(RasterLayer);

            // Add the graphics layer
            GraphLayer.AddChild(GraphNode);
            scene.AddLayer(GraphLayer);

            Width = width;
            Height = height;

            RasterLayer.PositionX = x;

            RasterLayer.PositionY = y;
            GraphLayer.PositionY = y;
        }

        public CCLayer RasterLayer { get; }
        public CCDrawNode RasterNode { get; }

        public CCLayer GraphLayer { get; }
        public CCDrawNode GraphNode { get; }

        float Width { get; }
        float Height { get; }

        // Buffer for the drawn items
        ConcurrentQueue<CalculationLog> List { get; }

        // Current position of the graph
        float Position { get; set; }

        // Here we get the new values for the graph
        public void AddValue(CalculationLog value)
        {
            List.Enqueue(value);
        }

        // This function will be called every 16ms
        public bool Draw()
        {
            while (List.TryDequeue(out CalculationLog value))
            {
                Position += Constants.GraphSpeed; // = 0.1f

                // If the position is bigger than 2 screen widths (* 1000 for ultra slow speeds)
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Position * 1000) >= Convert.ToInt32(Width * 2 * 1000))
                    Position = 0;

                // Calculate real positions
                var x = Position + RasterLayer.PositionX;
                var y = Convert.ToSingle(value.AccelerationUp / Constants.Scale) * (Height / 2) + Height / 2;

                if (y > Height) y = Height;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;

                var y2 = Convert.ToSingle(value.Height / Constants.Scale * 2) * (Height / 2) + 1;
                if (y2 > Height) y2 = Height;
                if (y2 < 0) y2 = 0;

                // Then draw them
                GraphNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x, 0), new CCPoint(x, Height), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.Black);
                GraphNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x, Height / 2), new CCPoint(x, y), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);
                GraphNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x, y2), new CCPoint(x, y2 + 1), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);

                GraphNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, 0), new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, Height), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.Black);
                GraphNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, Height / 2), new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, y), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);
                GraphNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, y2), new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, y2 + 1), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);
            }

            // Move the position of the graph layer
            GraphLayer.PositionX = Convert.ToInt32(Width - Position);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm actually drawing 2 graphs in 1 graph, I forgot this in my general description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems I was right. After testing it without drawing the graph the app didn't start stuttering. I now changed the graph to work with 2 layers, in pretty much the same way I used to do, only when I reset the scroll, I also reset the previous CCDrawNode with a:

```
GraphNode.Clear();
```

Full code:

```
public class ChartLayer
{
    public ChartLayer(CCScene scene, float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        List = new ConcurrentQueue<ICalculationLog>();

        RasterLayer = new CCLayer();
        RasterNode = new CCDrawNode();

        GraphLayer1 = new CCLayer();
        GraphNode1 = new CCDrawNode();

        GraphLayer2 = new CCLayer();
        GraphNode2 = new CCDrawNode();

        // Add the background layer
        RasterLayer.AddChild(RasterNode);

        // Draw the "zero lines"
        RasterNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(0, height / 2), new CCPoint(width, height / 2), 0.1f, CCColor4B.White);
        RasterNode.DrawLine(new CCPoint(0, 2), new CCPoint(width, 2), 0.1f, CCColor4B.White);
        scene.AddLayer(RasterLayer);

        // Add the graphics layer
        GraphLayer1.AddChild(GraphNode1);
        scene.AddLayer(GraphLayer1);

        GraphLayer2.AddChild(GraphNode2);
        scene.AddLayer(GraphLayer2);

        Width = width;
        Height = height;

        RasterLayer.PositionX = x;

        RasterLayer.PositionY = y;
        GraphLayer1.PositionY = y;
        GraphLayer2.PositionY = y;
    }

    public CCLayer RasterLayer { get; }
    public CCDrawNode RasterNode { get; }

    bool Node1Selected = false;


    public CCLayer GraphLayerForeground => Node1Selected ? GraphLayer1 : GraphLayer2;
    public CCDrawNode GraphNodeForeground => Node1Selected ? GraphNode1 : GraphNode2;
    public CCLayer GraphLayerBackground => Node1Selected ? GraphLayer2 : GraphLayer1;
    public CCDrawNode GraphNodeBackground => Node1Selected ? GraphNode2 : GraphNode1;

    public CCLayer GraphLayer1 { get; }
    public CCDrawNode GraphNode1 { get; }
    public CCLayer GraphLayer2 { get; }
    public CCDrawNode GraphNode2 { get; }

    float Width { get; }
    float Height { get; }

    // Buffer for the drawn items
    ConcurrentQueue<ICalculationLog> List { get; }

    // Current position of the graph
    float Position { get; set; }

    // Here we get the new values for the graph
    public void AddValue(ICalculationLog value)
    {
        List.Enqueue(value);
    }

    // This function will be called every 16ms
    public void Draw()
    {
        while (List.TryDequeue(out ICalculationLog value))
        {
            Position += Constants.GraphSpeed; // = 0.1f

            // If the position is bigger than 2 screen widths (* 1000 for ultra slow speeds)
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Position * 1000) >= Convert.ToInt32(Width * 2 * 1000))
            {
                Position = 0;
                Node1Selected = !Node1Selected;
                GraphNodeBackground.Clear();
            }

            // Calculate real positions
            var x = Position + RasterLayer.PositionX;
            var y = Convert.ToSingle((value.Acceleration.Z - 1) / Constants.Scale) * (Height / 2) + Height / 2;

            if (y > Height) y = Height;
            if (y < 0) y = 0;

            var y2 = Convert.ToSingle(value.Height / Constants.Scale * 2) * (Height / 2) + 1;
            if (y2 > Height) y2 = Height;
            if (y2 < 0) y2 = 0;

            // Then draw them
            //GraphNode1.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x, 0), new CCPoint(x, Height), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.Black);
            GraphNodeForeground.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x, Height / 2), new CCPoint(x, y), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);
            GraphNodeForeground.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x, y2), new CCPoint(x, y2 + 1), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);

            //GraphNode1.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, 0), new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, Height), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.Black);
            GraphNodeBackground.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, Height / 2), new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, y), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);
            GraphNodeBackground.DrawLine(new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, y2), new CCPoint(x - Width * 2, y2 + 1), Constants.GraphSpeed, CCColor4B.White);
        }

        // Move the position of the graph layer
        GraphNodeForeground.PositionX = Convert.ToInt32(Width - Position);
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        GraphNode1.Clear();
    }
}
```